# angularjs saving $scope via a closure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Disclaimer that I'm new to angularjs :)

I have a controller that delegates to a service and I'm trying to preserve the $scope so I can scope.apply after setting properties:

```
var Build = function($scope, $http, mango) {
    var scope = $scope;
    $scope.BuildManagerSubmit = function(selectedProfile) {
        mango.buildMango(selectedProfile.def, function(profiledef) {
            // bunch of property assignments on selectedProfile ...
            scope.$apply();
        }, scope);
    };
};
controllers.controller('Build', ['$scope', '$http', 'mango', Build]);
```

Notice that I'm using the closure to save the scope and passing it in to the service (omitted for brevity). The service calls me back like cb.call(context, ...) so I maintain access to scope. This is all working fine, but I'm more concerned with whether there's a better idiom. I don't see a lot of examples of maintaining $scope when delegating out to services like this.

EDIT: this application is using node-webkit and the 'mango' service essentially is interacting with the file system to call out to shell scripts, etc.

Comment: What is doind mango.buildMango? there's angular services to auto-handle timeout or XMLHttpRequest so you don't have to do that kind of stuff

Comment: the application uses node-webkit and that mango service interacts with the file system

Comment: Ok, I would inject $rootScope in the mango service  and call $rootScope.$apply() from there. You don't have to worry anymore about that when you will use mango service in other places after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the mango service take care of that (inject $rootScope in it), and perhaps use promises to replace callbacks so it would look like that:

```
var Build = function($scope, $http, mango) {
    $scope.BuildManagerSubmit = function(selectedProfile) {
        selectedProfile.profileDef = mango.buildMango(selectedProfile.def);

        // do something when profileDef returned? (not always necessary)
        selectedProfile.profileDef.then(function(profileDef) {

        });
    };
};
controllers.controller('Build', ['$scope', '$http', 'mango', Build]);
```

Comment: But doesn't the service than need to be responsible for doing the assignments to selectedProfile properties (before calling $rootScope.apply()) since that's why we were calling apply in the first place? I'm not sure I'm happy with adding the responsibility of doing bindings to a service who's single responsibility was wrapping shell commands.

Comment: You don't tell your service to do bindings, you tell your service to notify angular that scope might have changed, any service doing asynchronous work outside angular should do that. Assignments (if neccessary, not sure about that, angular handle promises transparently so you don't usually need that), would be done in the `promise.then` like I suggested in the code